# Facing Issue while integrating CCAVENUE payment gateway

Tags: php, payment-gateway

While integrating the CCAVENUE payment gateway, I am facing below issue:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open() in /var/www/html/public/cc_avenue/Crypto.php:9 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/public/cc_avenue/ccavRequestHandler.php(27): encrypt('_token=hDCVYwQA...', 'D30D16C0C8198D3...') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/public/cc_avenue/Crypto.php on line 9

Crypto.php file:

```
<?php

/*
* @param1 : Plain String
* @param2 : Working key provided by CCAvenue
* @return : Decrypted String
*/

function encrypt($plainText,$key)
{
    $key = hextobin(md5($key));
    $initVector = pack("C*", 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f);
    $openMode = openssl_encrypt($plainText, 'AES-128-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $initVector);
    $encryptedText = bin2hex($openMode);
    return $encryptedText;
}

/*
* @param1 : Encrypted String
* @param2 : Working key provided by CCAvenue
* @return : Plain String
*/
function decrypt($encryptedText,$key)
{
    $key = hextobin(md5($key));
    $initVector = pack("C*", 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f);
    $encryptedText = hextobin($encryptedText);
    $decryptedText = openssl_decrypt($encryptedText, 'AES-128-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $initVector);
    return $decryptedText;
}

function hextobin($hexString) 
 { 
    $length = strlen($hexString); 
    $binString="";   
    $count=0; 
    while($count<$length) 
    {       
        $subString =substr($hexString,$count,2);           
        $packedString = pack("H*",$subString); 
        if ($count==0)
        {
            $binString=$packedString;
        } 

        else 
        {
            $binString.=$packedString;
        } 

        $count+=2; 
    } 
        return $binString; 
  } 
?>
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Are you sure that is the correct file?

Comment: I am using 7.2, and this file is provided by CCAVenue only, they are providing PHP_Kit to integrate the payment gateway.

Comment: This is a [PHP module](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-module-open.php) Check that you have it installed with `php -m`

Comment: [Install here](https://lukasmestan.com/install-mcrypt-extension-in-php7-2/)